# Can't limit Object's Rotation Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object in my scene that move forward and rotate with input.GetAxis, and I want to limit its X rotation between -45 and 45 degree. So I tried the Clamp method but the object can't rotate anymore! is there something wrong in my code?

```
float Speed = 10f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    transform.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 2f, 0, -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));

    float rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.rotation.x, -45.0f, 45.0f);
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationX, transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Did the code work before adding ```Clamp```?

Comment: @Eric yes, it works perfectly without Clamp

Comment: Try ```print(transform.rotation.x)``` and tell me what you get

Comment: @Eric I got some values like: 0.3826835,0.3663827,0.2252642...

Comment: @Eric any suggestions?

Comment: No, I'm very confused

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't try setting localEulerAngles directly, I'd reset the rotation to Quaternion.Identity (no rotation) or to another reference transform's rotation and then use Transform.rotate rotationX degrees around the desired axis whenever the rotation changes

Comment: Can you please explain more :)

Comment: so it'd look something like:

Comment: Store the rotationX value and modify that directly, reset the transform's rotation to a default rotation and then call transform.rotate on the rotationX value you are handling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue your having atm is transform.rotation is a Quaternion and not a vector3. Since Quaternions have a min/max value of -1/1 the vector3 X rotation can't ever be outside that range.

You probably wanted to do: float rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localEulerAngles.x, -45.0f, 45.0f);